# Facebook Like Box not showing on Wordpress

Tags: html, facebook, wordpress

I have an issue with the Facebook Like Box not displaying on a self-hosted Wordpres website, any ideas why this would be? I've successfully managed to add it to websites in the past, but it's simply not displaying and i literally don't have a clue as to why.

Help would be much appreciated.

Link: http://www.mostdealsforyou.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly read the [FAQ] -- questions that require someone to visit another site to "see" the problem are frowned upon, not the least of which is because once you solve the problem, the evidence of the problem simply disappears. Instead, include screenshots so anyone else visiting this question can see the issue as it happened. Also, unless you have a specific reason to do so (expiring links, for example), please do not obfuscate your links using a shortener. Many people will not visit a link if they don't know the destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have not embedded the JS in the site.
According to the Facebook Documentation, you need to put this in as early as you can in the body:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And your code seems different than what Facebook generated for me:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.mostdealsforyou.com/" data-send="true" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

**Alternatively, you could just use an iFrame:**

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mostdealsforyou.com%2F&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=292&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

If you want to change the behavior of this just checkout [Facebook's like button generator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

Comment: Hey, the code you added does work, but it isn't quite what i'm looking for. I want the exact same thing as per my website over at www.n8geeks.com, i really don't see what i could be doing wrong. The plugin i want to use is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ thanks!